# Insert rows? I tried but it keeps empty

Tags: c#, listview, subitem

I've a ListView (named ListView1).
I added 4 columns (with visual editor, property Column): NumeroLista,OrdenLista,NumElementos,TiempoOrdenamiento.

I'm sure the code is reached because before it is in a function called directly from class constructor.
I'm trying to fullfil it with the following code but it keeps blank (please notice: the arrays I'm using are inizialized in another part of the code):

```
int idx;
string tmp;
string[][] linea = new string[numListas][];
for (idx = 0; idx < numListas; idx++)
{
    linea[idx] = new string[3];
    linea[idx][0] = Convert.ToString(idx);
    switch(OrdenListas[idx]){
        case 0: linea[idx][1] = "Crescente"; break;
        case 1: linea[idx][1] = "Decrescente"; break;
        case 2: linea[idx][1] = "Aleatorio"; break;
        default: linea[idx][1] = "No especificado"; break;
    }
    linea[idx][2] = Convert.ToString(LongitudListas[idx]);
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
    lvi.SubItems.Add(linea[idx][0]);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(linea[idx][1]);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(linea[idx][2]);
    lvi.SubItems.Add("test");
    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    listView1.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Have you set the `View` property of the Listview to `Details`? Also, refreshing the listview after item insertion is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forget to set `listview's` [ListView.View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.view.aspx) to `Details`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. It works. but... it displays second,third and fourh column (first attribute on second column,second attribute on third column,..). How could I fix it?

Comment: The first column shows the text of the ListViewItem itself. So pass `linea[idx][0]`to the ListViewItem constructor instead of using a sub item for it.

Comment: Do you mean pass a string ( linea[idx][0] ) + an array (of the elements left) so in total two elements?